# Como converter Hora:minutos:segundos para numero decimal no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando converter uma coluna no data.frame que esta no formato de hora:minutos: segundo para numero decimal
Exemplo:
2:20:00 para 2,33

Como posso fazer isso no R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como não tenho acesso ao teu conjunto de dados original, vou assumir que as horas não estão em formato de date, mas sim de caracter, tipo "h:m:s".

Eu criei a função `HoraDecimal`, que faz exatamente o que tu precisa. Veja ela abaixo:

```
HoraDecimal <- function(x){
  sum(unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, split=":"), as.numeric)) * c(1, 1/60, 1/3600))
}
```

Ela faz o seguinte:

- A função `strsplit` separa a string original de acordo com os ":". Por isso, toda entrada desta função deve estar no formato h:m:s, mesmo que sejam 0 horas.
- `lapply`, combinada com `as.numeric`, serve para transformar os caracteres obtidos com a função anterior em números
- `unlist` faz a lista criada por `lapply` virar um vetor
- Ao multiplicar este vetor por `c(1, 1/60, 1/3600)`, eu obtenho os valores que me interessam em frações de hora
- Por fim, `sum` faz a soma e organiza o resultado final

Veja a função `HoraDecimal` em aplicada a dados de hora no formato "h:m:s":

```
x <-  "02:20:00"
HoraDecimal(x)
[1] 2.333333

y <-  "00:50:00"
HoraDecimal(y)
[1] 0.8333333

z <- "3:30:30"
HoraDecimal(z)
[1] 3.508333
```

Comment: Pode-se usar `sapply` em vez de `unlist/lapply`, uma vez que a primeira por defeito simplifica a saída devolvendo um vector.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Muito obrigado! era exatamente isso que eu estava preicsando

Comment: @MarcusNunes Foi feita hoje uma pergunta semelhante no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770763/converting-time-data-frame-to-numeric-data/45770977?noredirect=1#comment78500153_45770977).

Comment: Que bacana saber que ajudei mais gente :-)

Comment: @LucianoHauschild, que bom que a resposta te ajudou! Seria possível aceitá-la para que mais pessoas com a mesma dúvida pudessem ser ajudadas no futuro? [https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) este link mostra o como e o porquê de fazer isto.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o lubridate
para instalar

```
install.packages("lubridate")
```

para carregar o library

```
library("lubridate")
```

primeiro convertendo seu string para formato de horário e depois convertendo para um valor decimal

```
y <- hms(x)
hour(y) + minute(y) / 60 + second(y) / 360
```